# Checking next 10 item greater than a value

Tags: python

Let say I've array of 100 items. I want to find n'th element is less than next all 10 elements. I can search by index but need short and elegant way.

```
import random
a = random.sample(range(10, 60), 100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case using `numpy` is fine you could use a rolling window as follows

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.choice(range(10, 60), 100)
win = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(a, 11)
mask = (win[:, 0] < win[:, 1:].T).all(axis=0)
indexes = np.where(mask)
print(indexes)
```

The idea is to crate a view which contains n+1 value so you can compare in each row (window) if the first element `win[:, 0]` is grater than all the following `win[:, 1:]`. Than you use `argmax` to find the first index you are looking for. You could also use `np.where` to get all indexes.

If using `numpy` is not an option, you could crate a rolling window with a `collections.deque` as follows:

```
import random
from collections import deque

values = deque(random.choices(range(10, 60), k=100))
win = deque((values.popleft() for _ in range(10)))
index = 0
indexes = []
while values:
    value = win.popleft()
    win.append(values.popleft())
    if all(value < w for w in win):
        indexes.append(index)
    index += 1
print(indexes)
```

Edit: I had the condition wrong and was searching for elements grater than all next 10...

Answer (score 0):

here a solution, would return the None if not possible or the then array-element plus the position of the first element?

```
def T(sample, value):
    nx = iter(sample)
    n, p , i = [], len(sample), 0
    while len(x)<10 and i<p:
        x = next(nx)
        if x < value:
            n.append(x)
        else:
            n.clear()
        i+=1 
    return n, i-10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.choice(range(10, 60), 100)
```

Copied from Carlos Horn. Thanks!

```
print(a)
```

Then you see the data.

```
n = [n for n in range(0, 90) for m in range(n + 1, n + 11) if a[n] < a[m]]
```

This line iterates over first 90 list elements and feeds array n if the next 10 elements are greater then a[n].

```
m = set(n)
```

distinct elements in array n.

```
[x for x in m if n.count(x) == 10]
```

x corresponds at the goal position.

Example of data:
input: [38 37 49 52 10 31 29 32 34 37 58 12 54 43 24 18 39 15 25 21 39 59 11 23
51 16 51 27 17 38 15 49 42 41 42 55 41 46 55 16 13 17 28 25 10 34 49 44
30 15 51 46 48 35 44 19 55 54 19 57 23 30 56 55 55 11 22 12 34 33 19 53
35 29 44 28 25 34 11 13 44 25 37 55 43 43 50 36 16 40 57 31 55 39 31 41
27 52 48 18]

output
[4, 11, 22, 44, 49, 65, 67, 78, 79, 88]

ie: numbers 10, 12, etc..